# 16 GB Crucial RAM For MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory

I'm looking to upgrade my MacBook Pro to 16GB of RAM. I'm considering:

- [Crucial 16GB (2 x 8GB) DDR3 1333MHz PC3-10600 204pin SODIMM CL9 Mac](http://www.dabs.com/products/crucial-16gb--2-x-8gb--ddr3-1333mhz-pc3-10600-204pin-sodimm-cl9-mac-891L.html?refs=50090-55260000&catid=15007&src=3)

The specs match what my MacBook wants from RAM but it doesn't specifically state which models it is compatible with. Are the MacBooks very fussy about RAM or could someone tell me if this is compatible with my MacBook?

Specs are as follows:

> - Late 2011 Macbook Pro 15″ (8,2)
> - 2.4 GHz Intel Core i7
> - 4 GB 1333Mhz DDR3 RAM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MacBooks with replaceable RAM use typical DDR3 like any other PC laptop.

From http://support.apple.com/kb/SP644:

> 1333MHz DDR3 SDRAM; supports up to 8GB

The RAM you linked to:

> - DDR3 SDRAM
> - Memory Speed 1333 MHz ( PC3-10600 )

I cannot guarantee that your MacBook will be able to address all 16GB, since the technical specifications claim the maximum supported amount is 8GB. However, I've seen several cases in which the upper bound Apple lists as "supported" is incorrect, so it's worth a shot. Make sure the RAM you buy has a decent return policy, in case your MacBook can't use more than 8GB as per the technical specifications.

Comment: Rate up and accept the answer if it helped (click the up arrow and checkmark on the top left of my answer)

Comment: i gave u  points, 7 more until you can rate up